# Netbeans 6.9.1 javadoc not found on mac osx 10.6.7

Tags: netbeans, javadoc, osx-leopard

I have a strange problem in my Netbeans compiler. Everytime i double click on method or anything, in javadoc the following message shows up.

> `private class MyCanvas extends JPanel`
>   Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or you have not added
>   specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager.

I use Mac osx 10.6.7 and i have downloaded a new version of javadoc and added it from the platform manager but the problem seems to continue. What could I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a well known issue. Try to follow this [link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJavaDoc#MacOS_Platform_Specific_Info) to solve it.

Links to documentation can be found [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJavaDoc#Adding_the_JDK_Javadoc_to_the_NetBeans_IDE).

I hope this helps.

Comment: i can see that the some folders mentioned are not found in my system. The main problem is that i have not found any javadoc files to download for mac from the oracle site.

Comment: Updated the post with the links to download the documentation.

Comment: thank you a lot!!! all i had to do is to download the html javadoc and add it from the platform manager.